# JMSSerializerBundle throws error when deserializing YAML

Tags: serialization, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to deserialize a YAML file using `JMSSerializerBundle` with `Symfony 3.3`. Running this code:

```
$yaml = $this->serializer->serialize($obj, "yml");
dump($yaml);  // This shows valid YAML content
$result = $this->serializer->deserialize($yaml, ObjCls::class, "yml");
```

produces: `The format "yml" is not supported for deserialization`. So, serializing works but not deserializing. The above code works well with `json` and `xml`, but not with 'yml'.

Is there some configuration I have to change in order to deserialize YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `JMSSerializerBundle` does not deserialize YAML (June 2017). I had to switch to XML. Too bad, I like YML format.